# Reverse/Offset order of one column into another with variable last row

Tags: vba, excel, formula, reverse, offset

O1 = OFFSET(**$B$last**, -(Row(B1)-1, 0)

The problem I have with the above formula is that the last row of column B can be any number (variable called increment) and I know you cannot use variables named in a macro as part of cell formulas. How would I go around this where "last" can be any number.

Also, is the above formula correct if I want to take the values in column be a copy them into column O in reverse order?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Addressing the first part of the problem.

**Now VBA Way**

This formula will be in Cell O1. Please note that if you are using Excel 2003 then change 1048576 to 65536. This is an array formula. It means that you will have to press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd> in lieu of simple <kbd>ENTER</kbd> key

```
=OFFSET(INDIRECT("$B$" & MAX(ROW(1:1048576)*(B:B<>""))), -(ROW(B1)-1), 0)
```

**VBA Way**

```
LastRow = ws.Range("B" & ws.Rows.Count).End(xlup).Row
Range("O1").Formula = "=OFFSET($B$" & LastRow & ", -(ROW(B1)-1), 0)"
```

Second part of the problem

> Also, is the above formula correct if I want to take the values in column be a copy them into column O in reverse order?

I will have to test it before commenting. Will update soon.

Answer (score 0):

It's not very clear from your question, but I think you might be looking for a formula a bit like this:

`=OFFSET($B$1,(COUNTA($B:$B)-ROW($B1)),)`

Paste it into **O1** and drag down.

Let me know how it works?

Comment: This will replace an *embedded blank* in column **B** with a zero in column **O**

Comment: If the values are complete in column **B** this will reverse them in column **O**. That's as much as I could get from the question. See: last paragraph.

Comment: I guess you ignored my comment by mistake :)